# Asp.net core To elastic beanstalk error 404 after deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, asp.net, elastic-beanstalk, .net

I have an asp.net core web api that run an 404 after it get's deployed to elastic beanstalk. Any version from 1.0 to 5.0 all show the same error 404.

The api works just fine on localhost but once it get uploded to elasticbeanstalk. It dosn't show anything.

Here is the full error.

**This aspnetcoretoelasticbeanstalk-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://aspnetcoretoelasticbeanstalk-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/**

HTTP ERROR 404

If somone can help me on this, i'll really appreciate. Thank you in advance !!